# Are all the mods trinitarians?

Tags: discussion, moderators

There seems to be persistent pro-trinitarian bias on Christianity SE. Are there any non-trinitarian mods on C SE?

Comment: Mason Wheeler at least has a LDS background. I don't know what his current beliefs are.

Comment: @curiousdannii Never encountered Mason Wheeler in a moderating role that I can remember - didn't even know he was one. Always you, Peter Turner, Ken Graham. How active is Wheeler in his moderating role nowadays?

Comment: Less active, but not inactive.

Comment: Cleaned up the comments as a separate question was asked on moderator activity.

Answer (score 3):

I thoroughly disagree with your claim. I have had far stronger moderation in regard to my own questions and answers (who am a lifelong Trinitarian) than the answer which prompted your present question.

The site requires persistent and forceful moderation or it would descend into argumentative chaos very quickly.

Until I really appreciated the difficulties of maintaining a site such as this, I, too, had many questions and many comments directed at my work. And the discipline did me good, nor do I object in the slightest.

As I observed today, your answer was incorrect and not in keeping with the spirit of the question. Your answer was merely a link to a very poorly expressed piece of writing which in no way answered the question.

The question was about Early Church Christians which the vast majority would take to be Christians in the early Church and their response to the apostolic teaching of the apostles.

The linked article took the words of the apostles and misrepresented  their teaching, but did not, once, quote from persons in the early church *who received that teaching*.

The response from moderation was purely on academic grounds, the correct procedure to answer that particular question.

I disagree entirely with your assessment of the situation.

I believe it to be unfounded.

Comment: "not in keeping with the spirit of the question" I asked the OP before answering whether he'd be interested in a NT answer. He said "A priori, I don't see any reason why not. If you can properly justify why you think the NT denies the divinity of Jesus beyond any reasonable doubt, then sure, go ahead and quote the NT as your source." You're wrong! "who received that teaching" How in the world do you know this?

Comment: Although, this isn't really a response to the question I asked.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg It's unfortunate the OP said that, however I can't see how that kind of question would be in scope here. We want to avoid sectarian bickering, not invite it with such questions. I think the question as it is now is essentially objectively answerable, which would not be the case if its scope included NT authors.

Comment: @curiousdannii "however I can't see how that kind of question would be in scope here" Seems pretty clearly in scope if it's a Biblical Basis question. No?

Comment: But it wasn't a Biblical Basis question? I don't know what you're trying to say.

Comment: @curiousdannii Why are you saying it couldn't be a Biblical Basis question? The OP said he was interested in a Biblical Basis answer.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg It's a church history question, completely different from a Biblical basis question. A Biblical basis question would be "what is the Biblical basis for rejecting the divinity of Jesus?" which would be fine, but it's not what was asked.

Comment: @curiousdannii How do you know it was a church history question? The OP said he was open to it being a Biblical Basis question. It seems it was actually a hybrid until you arbitrarily modified the question. Are hybrid Church History - Biblical Basis questions not allowed on C SE?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg No, the OP never said that. They said they were open to the NT being used as evidence of early church beliefs. And it is. It would be appropriate to include in a book on the early church. But I don't think it's the kind of evidence that can be used in productive answers here. But I'm only one person, and if you want to make your case that your answer should be undeleted, please do so, in a new Meta post.

Comment: @curiousdannii Why do you think the Biblical basis for something isn't evidence? To the extent there is a Biblical basis for something, that is *evidence* for that something. You seem to have 2 different categories, Biblical Basis and Church History, and never shall the two meet! In reality, evidence for 1st C Church History is largely what's in the NT.

Answer (score 0):

Do you believe that Jesus and Mary Magdalene were married?  If you don't, and you noticed a user coloring all their answers with that assertion whether or not it belonged, would you flag that post?  If you did flag that post, you left it up to a mod to decide what to do with it.  The mod can

1. put a long winded warning that turns into an argument
2. put an automatic post notice that never gets acted on
3. delete the post with a comment
4. delete the post with no comment
5. do nothing
6. leave it to another mod

The most likely thing to happen is for the post to be deleted, it stops further argument, forces the user the correct *something* if they want to participate in good faith and if it is ignored, then it's at least not another broken window.

So to this example, if you were of Dan Brown's ilk and you liked to post about that all the time, you might find yourself deleted.  If I post about Mary as Mediatrix of All Graces on everything, that'll be deleted too. There's lots of ways to get your posts deleted.

Comment: Yes, your post reminds me of at least one Catholic member of this site whose posts get deleted far more frequently than anyone else involved in this discussion here!

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg you're asking if all the mods are Trinitarians, but that's utterly irrelevant. I used to complain that all the mods on Programmse.SE weren't real programmers. (then they changed the name of the site and I don't hang out there any more).  The real question is "are the mods patient and fair?"  If the answer is no, then we have a problem, but I don't think the answer is no.  I do think we could stand to leave negative vote-getting answers undeleted and not go out of our way to delete them unless someone flags 'em. But I'm not sure that applies in your case.

Comment: "But I'm not sure that applies in your case." What do you mean by this?

Comment: @PeterTurner Why did you post this answer about Jesus and Mary Magdalene? What does it have to do with the question?

Comment: @anthony just making an analogy,  what does your question have to do with the question?

Comment: @PeterTurner Just making an analogy to what?

Comment: To non-trinitarianism.  I'm hoping you'd take umbrage at the assertion that Our Lord was married,  but at the very least you'd see that bringing up that sort of an idea would only be appropriate on questions where it is asked for.  We don't allow "generic Christianity questions" here, if you see a question that looks like it should have multiple viable answers from different perspectives or is based on false premises, please Vote to Close or comment to that effect.  Answering the question just proves it is a bad question while wasting your time.