# Is high-level, abstract information about individual moderator actions on C SE confidential?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

Is high-level, abstract information about individual moderator actions on C SE confidential? For example, a given moderator has taken moderator actions x times in the last week.

Comment: Why do you want to know that in the first place?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Related to my mods question here https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7054/are-all-the-mods-trinitarians . The mod I was talking to claimed info on mod activity is confidential. I then asked for a link to where it says info on mod activity is confidential. No response yet from the mod.

Comment: Moderators are elected on Stack Exchange. That means that a majority of the Community wanted these individuals to do what they do. It was a Community decision. And they do a lot of hard work in the background, free of charge, in order that we may have a functioning site. I am not aware that there is a job called 'Moderator Scrutiniser' for which the Community may vote to elect such a person. Unless I missed the voting opportunity.

Comment: Some users are able to 'access moderator tools'. This requires 10,000 reputation points.

Answer (score 3):

Mods do a lot of things, and it's not possible to quantify all of it, nor is it really all that meaningful to compare between mods.

- User moderation (warnings, suspensions)
- Handling flags
- Cleaning up the site, closing questions, deleting posts and comments
- Using the review queues (a moderation action everyone can do, but it still counts when the mods do it)
- Crafting the custom close reasons, editing the help pages
- Adding post notices, protecting questions, removing questions from the HNQ list
- Commenting on problematic posts
- Welcoming new people and making the site a generally welcoming place
- Processing flag synonyms
- Responding on Meta
- Encouraging the community to *use* Meta
- Identifying disputes within the community, weighing arguments, and putting forward arguments for policies (not unilaterally deciding policies)
- Liaising with mods on other sites

The mods are not all equally active, nor do we all do all of these things to the same extent. There should be no expectation that all mods do contribute in the same ways, or that they spend the same amount of time here. It's not even like one action is always the same - some flags take 5 seconds to process, others could take half an hour to investigate,  decide a course of action, and then implement it. Some Meta posts take 3 minutes to write, others take an hour.

Some information is confidential, like user moderation actions. If someone is suspended we won't tell you why. Some of these actions you can observe yourself. Others you can't. Even when you can observe them you can't always know how much time or energy was put into it.

Finally, I see no reason to present a report on the other mods to the community. We're a team, and I don't think that would feel supportive to the other mods. At the moment I feel like we're adequate staffed for the amount of activity this site gets. If that's the case, then it doesn't really matter how we divide up the work. If anyone feels like moderation is taking too long, or if you think we're not spending enough time making decisions, then you can discuss it here, or raise the problems with SE staff.

Comment: Well stated if  stated  myself!

Comment: This contains some interesting information, but it doesn't directly answer the question. Is high-level, abstract information about individual moderator actions on C SE confidential? For example, a given moderator has taken moderator actions x times in the last week.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather I don't know if it's strictly confidential from SE's perspective, but it's practically confidential from ours.

Comment: @curiousdannii What do you mean, it's 'practically confidential'?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather I mean in practical terms, we're not going to tell you. At least not without you making a really good case for it.

Comment: @curiousdannii Thank you for that clarification - can you point me to where the community decided those rules?